How to make Soap Client application (running in java jre1.8.0_131) to send Soap request with Server Name Identification (SNI)?
I am trying to send Soap Request from Java application (version 1.8.0_131) running in Tomcat version (apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26), to another Soap WebService (Java 17 and TLSV2) running in cloud.
And I am seeing, below Connection reset error, in SSL debug log.
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 209
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
main, called closeSocket()
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed

My Soap Webservice application supports only TLSv2, and it expects Server Name Identification (SNI) from client's soap Request.
Soap Client doesnt send SNI in Soap requet as this version jre1.8.0_131 has bug (as in 12th of https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u141-bugfixes.html).
If I send sample soap request to the server using curl command, connection is successful and able to get successful soap response.
If I remove the HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier() function from the client application, it sends soap request with SNI and connection is successful. But I believe, it is not the right approach.
As I am not allowed to upgrade java version of the Soap Client application, Is there any other way to make Soap Client (running in jre1.8.0_131 and apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26) to send Soap request with SNI?
